# Read non constant c string into string class

Tags: c++

I need to read a non-constant C string into a C++ string. However, I only see methods in the string class that read constant C strings into the string class.

Is there anyway to do this in C++?

Update:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string a;

    // other code here

    a(argv[0]);

    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:11:14: error: no match for call to '(std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}) (char*&)'
     a(argv[0]);
```

I did some more investigation, and replaced argv[0] with a constant string, and found that I still got a similar error message. A better question would now be: *How can I declare an object and call its constructor later?*

Comment: Show code. What do you have in code till now?

Comment: "Off topic"?  You people are ridiculous.

Comment: I've added code. Looks like my original diagnosis of the problem was incorrect.

Comment: *""How can I declare an object and call its constructor later* - You can't, nor do you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what the function signatures mean.  The conversion takes its argument as a `const char *`, but that doesn't mean that you cannot pass a `char*` to it.  It's just telling you that the function will not modify its input. Why don't you just try it out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    char str[] = "hello";
    std::string cppstr = str;
    std::cout << cppstr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More specifically, *objects* of type std::string are not callable, only std::string's constructor can is callable.